# Why does Console.Write write a full line on laptop

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I sometimes work on a laptop locally and sometimes remote into a desktop machine.

Both have the same OS and version:

> OS Name:      Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
> OS Version:   10.0.19045 N/A Build 19045

But when I run a project that runs as a console application, I get different results depending on whether the solution is on the laptop or the desktop machine.

On my desktop machine running the project where there is a loop with this code:

```vb
  System.Console.Write($"{vbCr}{"".PadLeft(Console.CursorLeft, " "c)}")
  System.Console.Write($"{vbCr}Getting info for table: {tbl.Name}")
```

causes that line to get overwritten (as intended), on my laptop, that works as effectively a writeline (not what I want).

Why? And what do I do so that it works correctly on the laptop?

Comment: `$"{vbCr}{"".PadLeft(Console.CursorLeft, " "c)}"` <-- _...the heck_?

Comment: @Dai: what don't you understand?  VB string interpolation? Or what that line is supposed to do?  It uses Carriage return to go the beginning of the line, and then overwrite the existing characters on the line with spaces.

Comment: No, I get that - it's just I'm surprised you're able to use the `CursorLeft` property like that and not have any glitches. IIRC, it's updated kinda-asynchronously w.r.t. stdout writes (because stdout to the console can be bufferd)

Comment: And that could be the problem/solution.  I'll see what happens when I add System.Console.Out.Flush()

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a hint by Dai, I was able to fix the problem.  Apparently Console.CursorLeft isn't updated in real time, by adding `System.Console.Out.Flush()` before the write's, it is now acting correctly on my laptop. Buffer size was the same on both machines.

Still not quite sure of **why** this was happening (I would have expected different behavior if `CursorLeft` was zero or some other value), but it does fix my immediate problem.

Comment: BTW, Microsoft now recommends people use Virtual Terminal Sequences instead of the "Classic" Windows Console API - so you might want to consider swapping out `CursorLeft` with something more portable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/classic-vs-vt

Comment: @Dai, LOL everything old is new again. I remember ANSI escape code sequences from '80s BBS days...